# how to make loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

i need to select data from table named booked from a given range of data and display data form a variable and then used it to select from another table and display the data that is selected but when the data that is selected from table booked is multiple only the first data is displayed in the variable here's my code:

```
$res1=mysqli_query($bd,"select * from booked where  datefrom between '$from' and '$to' or dateto>='$from' and dateto='$to'");
$num1=mysqli_num_rows($res1);
if($num1>0)
{
   for($y=0;$y<$row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1);$y++)
   {
       $res=mysqli_query($bd,"select * from rooms where capacity>='$newcap' and room_number!='".$row1['roomnumber']."'");
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
       {
          echo'<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">';
                echo'<div class="newsBox">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <figure><img src="reservation/img/rooms/'.$row['img'].'"  width="230" height="150"></figure>
                        <div class="caption maxheight2">
                        <div class="box_inner">
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <a class="title"><strong>'.$row['name'].'</strong></p>
                                        <b>'.$row['description'].'</b>
                                        <p>'.$row['price'].'</p>
                                    </div>
                                  <a class="btn btn-default" href="info_pay.php?roomnumber='.$row['room_number'].'&roomtype='.$row['name'].'&from='.$_POST['from'].'&adult='.$_POST['adult'].'&child='.$_POST['child'].'&to='.$_POST['to'].'&roomprice='.$row['price'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Select this Room</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            echo'</div>';
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: sorry im just a beginner can u help me with my code?

Comment: You should explain what you want your code to do that the pasted code does not achieve.

Comment: it is a resort reservation system and that is form making reservation. what i need to achieve is if someone already reserved that date that he/she selected the room will be hidden

Comment: From what I can see you can avoid looping inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to to try a different approach using [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) as it is less prone to quoting errors, here's a complete example to loop a `mysqli` query using `heredoc`.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="select * from booked where  datefrom between '$from' and '$to' or dateto>='$from' and dateto='$to'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
echo <<< LOL
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="newsBox">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <figure><img src="reservation/img/rooms/{$row['img']}"  width="230" height="150"></figure>
                        <div class="caption maxheight2">
                        <div class="box_inner">
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <a class="title"><strong>{$row['name']}</strong></p>
                                        <b>{$row['description']}</b>
                                        <p>{$row['price']}</p>
                                    </div>
                                  <a class="btn btn-default" href="info_pay.php?roomnumber={$row['room_number']}&roomtype={$row['name']}&from={$_POST['from']}&adult={$_POST['adult']}&child={$_POST['child']}&to={$_POST['to']}&roomprice={$row['price']}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Select this Room</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
LOL;

  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

}
//close mysqli connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```